# How to check if all the lines in an 2D Array have the same size

Tags: java, arrays

So I have my fancy 2D Char array that has something like this inside of it:

```
WWWSWWWW\n
WWW_WWJW\n
W___WWWW\n
__WWWWWW\n
W______W\n
WWWWWWEW\n
```

I need to write an exception that when reading this, it checks if all the lines have the same length, and if not, it returns a custom exception.

Here's some of what I have right now

```
for (int i = 0; i < contalinhas; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < linelenght; j++) {
            System.out.print(linhaslidas[i].charAt(j));
            storelab[i][j] = linhaslidas[i].charAt(j);
            String linha = linhaslidas[i].get
            //builder.append(storelab[i][j]);
            //builder.toString();
            //System.out.print(builder);

            if (storelab[i][j] != ('S') && storelab[i][j] !=  ('W') && storelab[i][j] !=  ('_') && storelab[i][j] !=  ('E')) {
                throw new MazeFileWrongChar(i,j);
```

As you can see, I already have an "If" to serve as another exception (basically, to limit what kind of characters are allowed), so I'd like to make something similar that goes through the array and counts the length of each line. If it detects atleast one size difference, an exception will occur.

The thing is, I have no idea how to code it, since I'm using an array and not a string for example (different methods).

Any help?

Comment: It looks like you already have `linelength` that you are using to loop through j. So, why not `if (linhaslidas[i].length != linelength) throw new MazeSizeWrongException();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could run over the first index of the array and compare the size of the arrays:

```
int initialLen = storelab[0].length;

// Iterate from index 1, as we already got 0
for (int i = 1; i < contalinhas; i++) {
    int currLen = storelab[i].length;
    if (initialLen != currLen) {
        throw new SomeException();
    }
}
```

EDIT:
If you're using Java 8, you could use streams to get a slightly more elegant solution, albeit less performant:

```
long lenths = Arrays.stream(storelab).mapToInt(s -> s.length).distinct().count();
if (lengths != 1L) {
    throw new SomeException();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following example:

```
public class ExampleStrings {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] valid = {"aaa", "bbb", "ccc"};
        String[] invalid = {"aaa", "bbb", "1ccc"};

        // will pass with no exception
        allTheSameLength(valid);

        // will throw an exception with appropriate message
        allTheSameLength(invalid);
    }

    private static void allTheSameLength(String[] arr) {
        if (arr == null || arr.length == 0) {
            return; // or false - depends on your business logic
        }

        // get length of first element
        // it is safe to do because we have previously checked
        // length of the array
        int firstSize = arr[0].length();

        // we start iteration from 'second' element
        // because we used 'first' as initial
        for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (arr[i].length() != firstSize) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("String array elements have different sizes"); // or throw exception
            }
        }

    }

}
```

It is safe to pass `null` or empty argument.